# how to access depth values form /camera/depth/image_raw?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, depth-image, sensor-msgs#image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey ,

i am using ros hydro and ubuntu 12.04 (LTS) , i need to know how to convert the 8-bit depth data which i receive from kinect in the topic /camera/depth/image_raw to depth of individual points in mm . i know that we have to use encoding and is_bigendian values , but i dont know how to use them . can someone please guide me how to use them .

Note: i didnt want to use point cloud data type because it was a bit complicated when compared to /camera/depth/image_raw and i only need depth data , so i thought this was better . if you feel that in order to access depth data point clouds are better please guide me how to obtain the depth data from point cloud .

Thank you for your patience .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150941/how-to-access-depth-values-form-/camera/depth/image_raw??/) by [hunterkaushik](https://answers.ros.org/users/12241/hunterkaushik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-04-08**:
Do you mean something like this http://answers.ros.org/question/141741/calculate-depth-from-point-cloud-xyz/?answer=141756#post-id-141756

**Comment by [hunterkaushik](https://answers.ros.org/users/12241/hunterkaushik/) on 2014-04-09**:
no , i want to know how to get the values x,y,z in the first place , also the time taken for my robot to read point cloud data is very high like 4sec difference between one input and the other , how do i rectify it ?? please help me out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this Q&A helps: http://answers.ros.org/question/125241/how-to-use-depth-value-from-cameradepthimage/#127121

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-06-25**:
it works perfect for `/camera/depth/image_raw` rostopic.

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2021-06-25**:
My answer with complete code (c++) : https://answers.ros.org/question/141741/calculate-depth-from-point-cloud-xyz/?answer=381085#post-id-381085